# Does Automapper preserve mapped list item order?

Tags: automapper

I could not find information on List item mapping order in Automapper's documentation or unit tests. If I try to map a `new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 }` to another `List<int>`, can I be sure that a new list will always have items `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` in the same order?

Automapper's unit tests regarding lists only check if a new list contains the items and have no assumptions regarding item order.

Comment: Because with the C# type system you cannot describe that the mapping operation keeps the order you can only relay on the documentation or the units test if any of them exits. If you find that nothing is written down regarding keeping the order then it is not part of the operation contract so you should count on it (even if the current implementation of the `EnumerableMapperBase` uses a `foreach` and keeps the order)

Comment: I wrote tests with the assumption in case future implementations break the behavior, so I could at least notice it in time. For now I assume that the order will be preserved. I was hoping that someone would point me to some unit test or a piece of documentation I might have missed. Thanks.

Comment: The only trace what I quickly found which points to the direction that the keeping of the order is intentionally is the signature of the [SetElementValue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/develop/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/EnumerableMapperBase.cs#L81) abstract method which gets called from `Map` and takes an `index` argument...